# TVML/tvOS : How to make a loooong text scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, tvos, tvml

How is it possible to make a very long text scrollable in TVML?

So i have a "descriptiveAlertTemplate", with a description.
The problem now is, that the text is going further the border of my monitor (and i dont want to change the font of the text). I even have a button and a title, but they just arent showing since its all full of text thats cropped.

I tried to do it with "showsScrollIndicator = "true"" but not working either.

```
<description showsScrollIndicator="true" id="descText" >(heres my text)</description>
```